# Drawing orbit trial for a planet in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I'm currently doing a model of the solar system. I have a planet that moves around the sun. This is the planet:

```
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(theta * 10, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(P1[0], P1[1], P1[2]);
    gluSphere(quad, 0.05, 100, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
```

Now, I want to draw a trial around the sun exactly where the planet moves. How do I do this? I'm supposed to use GL_LINES to draw it. So far I've got this, but I'm not getting the desired result. The circular path isn't exactly the same as the rotation orbit of the planet.

```
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (float i = 0; i < 2 * PI; i += 0.01)
    {
        float x = P1[0] * cos(i) + 0.0;
        float y = 0.0;
        float z = P1[2] * sin(i) + 0.0;
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }
    glEnd();
```

Given the information about the planet, how do I draw its orbit trial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the planet is following a circular orbit, you need to know the center of the circle, the radius, and the axis of rotation. In your case, the axis of rotation is the y-axis. Therefore the points on along orbit can be computed by the trigonometric functions `sin` and `cos` Define a center point (`float CPT[3]`) and a radius (`float radius`). Use the [Line primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) type `GL_LINE_LOOP` to draw the circular orbit:

```c
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for (float angle = 0; i < 2 * PI; angle += 0.01)
{
    float x = CPT[0] + cos(angle) * radius;
    float y = CPT[1];
    float z = CPT[2] + sin(angle) * radius;
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: So my sun is at the center (0.0,0.0,0.0). Wouldn't that be the center point? If so, how is this different from the one I had in my post?

Comment: @SuryaKashyap Pleas read the answer. e.g.: `P1[0] * cos(i)` -> `cos(angle) * radius`

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry about that, I get it now